# R: trouble with specifying probability for sample function

Tags: r

```
> sample(c(2), 10, replace = TRUE, prob = 1)
Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities
> sample(c(1), 10, replace = TRUE, prob = 1)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

In the first example, I would like to sample the vector `2` ten times, with replacement, each with probability = 1. I would expect the output to be `2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2`

However, it seems to work with a vector of `1`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try removing the prob = 1 and what do you get?

```
> set.seed(123)
> sample(c(2), 10, replace = TRUE)
# [1] 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1
```

`help(sample)`

> **Usage**
>
> `sample(x, size, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)`
>
> If x has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and x >= 1,
>   sampling via sample takes place from 1:x. Note that this convenience
>   feature may lead to undesired behaviour when x is of varying length in
>   calls such as sample(x). See the examples.

So, it's sampling from `1:2` not `2`.

Comment: If you still want to include `prob` for some reason, you can do the following: `x <- 2` and then `sample(x, 10, replace = TRUE, prob = c(rep(0,x-1),1))`

Comment: `sample(2, 10, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0,1))`. I guess this is what you wanted to write.

Comment: Dave's solution would work for any integer. For example, if `x` was 3, you would need to manually change your `prob` to `c(0,0,1)` while Dave's solution handles that for you. However, I think the main problem was that the OP didn't realize that `sample` will sample from `1:x` if `x` is a numeric of length 1. It is probably easier to filter those out and use `rep`, and only apply `sample` if `length(x) > 1`, depending on the desired solution when x is a single value.